# Java SWT ModifyListener set a Boolean variable

Tags: java, swt

i am writing a small Text-Editor with Java SWT. 
If the textfield of the object "Text" are modified, the Listener have to set a boolean value to true, that the textfield was changed. And when i want to quit the editor it should ask me to save if the textfield was changed. But the boolean variable changes their value only in their ModifyListener? 
If i push on the quit button, the selectionlistener reacts and it should ask me to save, but it didn't ask to.

What is my failure?

```
public class ModifyListenerTextField implements ModifyListener {

 private Boolean changedTextField;

 public ModifyListenerTextField(Boolean changedTextField){
     this.changedTextField = changedTextField;
 }

 @Override
 public void modifyText(ModifyEvent arg0) {
     if(!changedTextField.booleanValue()){
         changedTextField = Boolean.TRUE;
     }
 }

}
```

Comment: Please post the complete code and clarify what doesn't work. As a note: There is no need to use a `Boolean` here, a `boolean` will do. And why do you pass it to the text field constructor?

Comment: I use the Boolean instead of the primitive boolean because i have to pass the reference of the boolean variable to Check if the variable is changeant to true ...

Comment: Why don't you just add a get function to your class that returns the boolean?

Comment: Do You mean a get function to My modifylisfener?

Comment: Add it to ModifyListenerTextField and return the boolean

Answer (score -1):

It is quite simple. You dont need to implement anything. You may alter the below code upon your will

```
JTextField field = new JTextField();

field.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                booleanVar = true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, got confused